# SWUpdate on RPi4 via yocto - error parsing configuration file

Tags: arm, 64-bit, yocto, raspberry-pi4, swupdate

After booting SWUpdate yocto-generated image for the first time, executing `swupdate` results in error message:

> Error parsing configuration file: 'globals' section missing, exiting.

I tried to strictly follow SWUpdate's documentation, but it gets short when it comes to yocto integration. I'm using meta-swupdate, meta-swupdate-boards, and meta-openembedded layers together with poky example repository all at Kirkstone tag, building via `bitbake update-image` and having modyfied `local.conf` as:

```
MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi4-64"
ENABLE_UART = "1"
RPI_USE_U_BOOT = "1"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "wic ext4.gz"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot-fw-utils = "libubootenv"

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " swupdate"
```

Is there anything else I need to modify to generate the configuration file and be able to run SWUpdate binary properly?

Side question: In the documentation, it's recommended to append `swupdate-www` to achieve a better web server. However, if I append it, there is no `swupdate-www` binary inside the `/usr/bin' directory.

Answer (score 0):

As with other recipes folders the `recipes-support/swupdate/swupdate/raspberrypi4-64` folder was missing inside the `meta-swupdate-boards` layer. Therefore, an empty config file was always generated. After adding this folder and all related files, strongly inspired by `raspberrypi3` folder, the error was gone and `swupdate -h` provided the expected output.

There was also one new error during build process thrown by yocto. It was related to missing systemd requirement and was solved by adding:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
```

to `local.conf`

Comment: could you please post your bblayers.conf? Im trying to do the same thing here :)

Comment: Sure:
```
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/meta-raspberrypi \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/meta-swupdate \
  /home/user/Projects/yocto/meta-swupdate-boards \
```

Comment: What you probably need is: https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate-boards/pull/9
We are discussing it here: https://groups.google.com/g/swupdate/c/iKesPPyqDFQ